How can i change notification icon background color
enter image description here
I want to change my apps notification icon as other notification. I'm using react-native-push-notifications module. I tried update Androidmanifest.xml but it didnt work. It has drawable and mipmap and color folder.

You can change background of whole notification by this code in native android :
NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext,NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID).setColorized(true).setColor(Color.parseColor("#f7da64")
but about background color of icon I think it is impossible you should add the drawable resource that matches you requirement.

Please check other notification in the screenshot. It has red background

It does not have background. It actually does not contain image resource and because it title starts with "A" you see this char on it.
